# How to access specific date format?

Tags: oracle, vb6

```
<code>
Private Sub CmbRNO_Click()
sql = "SELECT
          A.ROLLNO,A.FIRST_NAME,A.MIDDLE_NAME,A.LAST_NAME,A.CONTACT,A.CONTACT1,A.CONTACT2,A.ADDRESS,A.GRADE,B.DIV,A.BLOOD_GROUP,C.HOUSE,A.DATE_OF_BIRTH,A.TRANSPORT,A.SNAME,A.MEAL,A.BUSNO,A.RUTNO,D.DNAME,D.DCONT,E.ANM,D.DADD,A.CARD_TYPE,A.CARD_NO 
       FROM 
          STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE A,DIVISION B,HNM C,DRIVER D,ATTEND E 
       WHERE 
          A.DIVID=B.DIVID AND A.HID=C.HID AND A.DID=D.DID AND A.AID=E.AID AND ROLLNO ='" & CmbRNO.Text & "'"

Set RES = CON.Execute(sql)
        TxtFNM.Text = RES!FIRST_NAME
        TxtMIDNM.Text = RES!MIDDLE_NAME
        TxtLNM.Text = RES!LAST_NAME
        Text5.Text = RES!CONTACT
        Text6.Text = RES!CONTACT1
        Text7.Text = RES!CONTACT2
        TxtADDR.Text = RES!ADDRESS
        COMBO1.Text = RES!GRADE
        CmbDIV.Text = RES!DIV
        CmbBG.Text = RES!BLOOD_GROUP
        CmbHOUSE.Text = RES!HOUSE
        DTPicker1.Value = RES!DATE_OF_BIRTH     //error showing
        Combo10.Text = RES!TRANSPORT
        CmbSTOP.Text = RES!SNAME
        Combo11.Text = RES!MEAL
        CmbBUS.Text = RES!BUSNO
        Combo12.Text = RES!RUTNO
        CmbDRIVER.Text = RES!DNAME
        TxtDCONT.Text = RES!DCONT
        CmbATTEND.Text = RES!ANM
        Text10.Text = RES!DADD
        Combo13.Text = RES!CARD_TYPE
        Text11.Text = RES!CARD_NO
 End If
 End Sub
</code>
```

This is the full code to display student records on combo click
 
but error is: `Invalid property value date_of_birth`

Please help

Comment: Is this happening on all records, or perhaps only on those records with DATE_OF_BIRTH  = NULL   ?

Comment: sir,not for all records,only newly added records by vb...............

Comment: Try using IsDate or IsNull functions to check if the value really is a  non-NULL date before setting the DTPicker.Value.  The problem may be that your input is allowing NULL in a field you are not expecting a NULL.

Comment: I didn't set not null to the date format in oracle....

Comment: while adding new record I am setting date using dtpicker on application then why it is not displaying that date? perhaps why not accepting the date from dtpicker?

Comment: Is the value in the database a NULL?  If so, then you'll need to check how you are inserting the new record...

Comment: when I am inserting new record then I am selecting date from dtpicker.... is there any need to set date format for dtpicker????? I think database is not accepting the date given using vb

Comment: Can you maybe show the entire procedure? You've removed something from the code you pasted. Oh, and the datapicker doesn't accept a formatted date, it takes a date value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a result of difference in date format between oracle and vb6. To avoid that, I would explicitly define the date format while selecting the columns like this

```
SELECT
 A.ROLLNO,
 A.FIRST_NAME,
 A.MIDDLE_NAME,
 ...
 TO_CHAR(A.DATE_OF_BIRTH,'DD-MON-YYYY') DATE_OF_BIRTH
 ...
```

Then read it in VB6 by converting it into date:

```
DTPicker1.Value = CDate(RES!DATE_OF_BIRTH)
```